# Ignite cache access locks

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have application with multi-thread access to various Ignite cache objects.
I can't reproduce it steady but sometimes application hungs.

Thread dump stack shows that threads are hunging on access to Ignite cache objects. 
Thread dump stack: https://yadi.sk/d/Ac5cOi_f3Ejen7

Is it possible to help me to understand what is wrong with my application ?

1) threads dump stack attached. There are 2 threads with access to Ignite cache objects

2) cache configuration

```
<property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
<property name="startSize" value="500"/>
<property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
<property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
```

3) Problems can be occured in different places of the application. I have attached dump stack trace just for one case.

Thanks!

Comment: How many nodes do you have? Can you upload dumps and also log files from all of them?

Comment: 7 nodes, Currently all of them under one PC

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/ZEyHHlQr3ErcZZ  - dumps and logs

Comment: No files available by link.